# How to search XML node values with the same name and at the same level?

Tags: java, xml, cucumber, rest-assured

I am trying to use Cucumber and REST Assured to create autoamted tests in my Gradle project.

Below is the XML Response Body:

```
<ValidationResponse>
    <errors>
        <error>
            <field>id</field>
        </error>

        <error>
            <field>amount</field>
        </error>

    </errors>
</ValidationResponse>
```

I am trying to use the below REST Assured code to check that:

- "id" appears in the first error field
- "amount" appears in the second error field

  ```
  RestAssured.given()
  .auth()
  .preemptive()
  .basic(theUsername, thePassword)
  .contentType(theContentType)
  .header("Accept",theContentType)
  .body(theXMLBody)
  .when()
  .post(theURL)
  .then()
  .body("ValidationResponse.errors.error[0].field", equalTo("id"))
  .and()
  .body("ValidationResponse.errors.error[1].field", equalTo("amount"));
  ```

The second field is failing because the code is just checking the first "field" it runs into.

Does anybody know what changes I need to make to my code so that it checks the second "field" also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below snippet to validate the response fields.

```
String responseXMLAsString = "<ValidationResponse>     <errors>         <error>             <field>id</field>         </error>          <error>             <field>amount</field>         </error>      </errors> </ValidationResponse>";
    XmlPath xmlPath = new XmlPath(responseXMLAsString);
    assertThat(xmlPath.get("ValidationResponse.errors.error.field"), contains("id","amount"));
```

OR

```
RestAssured.given()
.auth()
.preemptive()
.basic(theUsername, thePassword)
.contentType(theContentType)
.header("Accept",theContentType)
.body(theXMLBody)
.when()
.post(theURL)
.then()
.body("ValidationResponse.errors.error.field", contains("id","amount"));
```

Where contains() is hamcrest matcher

```
import static org.hamcrest.collection.IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains;
```